# Load data from an object in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking at this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848) of D3.js version 4 and I need to load dynamic data from the same script.
What is the analogus function of [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#requests-d3-request) to load data from an array or an object? I don't need an XMLHttpRequest but I need the same behavior of `d3.csv()`.

A fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/i5ar/mbcu05z8/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mbcu05z8/27/

I stored the array in a variable just like you did:

```
var myArr= [{"id":"AL","Under 5":310504,"5 to 13":552339,"14 to 17":259034,"total":1121877},{"id":"AK","Under 5":52083,"5 to 13":85640,"14 to 17":42153,"total":179876},{"id":"AZ","Under 5":515910,"5 to 13":828669,"14 to 17":362642,"total":1707221}];
```

then I changed `d3.csv` to a custom function named `draw()` and just called it :-)

```
draw(myArr);
function draw(states) {
  var stateById = d3.map();
  states.forEach(function(d) {
    stateById.set(d.id, d);
  });

  setTimeout(()=>{  
    dispatch.call("load", window, stateById);
    dispatch.call("statechange", window, stateById.get("AL"));
  },20);
};
```